# Data modelling: Tables with many properties

Tags: postgresql, data-modeling, hstore

I have an entity called Project. Every project has group of members assigned to it. From every member I'm collecting some information, e.g. age, height etc.. Some of them are numerical-type, some text-type, some logical-type (boolean). There are several dozen of informations, which can be collected.

This, which information I'm collecting in particular project, defines the project itselves. In single project I used to collect several, like 3-5, informations. In some projects I can collect the same, or similar sets of informations. And this, what interests me, is making statistics of all projects, in which I have collected particular information.

The question is: what should be the architecture of the table(s) containing those informations? Having one big table with several dozen of columns with many null-values in each row doesn't sound good, especially since I will have thousands, or even millions of those in my database. But having a table per project (and as many tables, as many projects), in which I'm collecting only the information, doesn't sound good either, since to make a statistics from all of the projects would require using dynamic SQL (variable table names - depending on project) and iterating over hundreds of them. Also having a table per option, or even option-type (logical, text, boolean) doesn't seem to be the proper way to do it.

I'm using PostgreSQL database. I know, that some databases have something like ANYTYPE (e.g. sql_variant in Microsoft SQL Server, or ANYDATA in Oracle), but PostgreSQL doesn't, what makes me a little bit confused.

I'm quite sure there is a better solution for this, but I can't figure it out. Could you, please, help me to find it?

Thanks in advance for every single response.

Comment: "Database architecture planning"? This seems like a straight-up data modelling question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a table inheritance feature built in postgresql which let you run queries on a table hierarchy.

Look [there](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) and [there](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-inherit.html) in the postgresql documentation for a good tutorial.

These explain how to build tables inheriting from one table: all the fields in the parent table are automatically included in the child tables, and all queries run on a parent table are run on child tables (but not the opposit, or on sibling tables) and results are concatenated, unless the special keyword ALONE is used to qualify the query (or clause maybe) as restricted to a single table.
You should be careful with constraints, because they do not cross table boundaries. In other words, if a constraint is set on a parent table, it will be restrained to that table alone, and child or sibling tables might contain duplicate of rows in the constrained table.

Comment: Got your point and it's a good thing if I would have something like some main properties collected in every project, and project-classess defining what information we're collecting in particular type. But since every project can have completely different property set than the other ones, it's hard to organize them in something like parent-child structure, so this solution is good, but not exactly in my case.

Comment: Do you mean that there isn't a single common property to all your projects?

Comment: It depends on the user of this system, but if there isn't, I can always create something like artificial one, however ... Let's take an example: Project 1 collects information A, X, Y; project 2: A, X, Z; project 3: A, Y; project 4: A, Z; project 5: A, X, Y, Z. How to organize it? Do I need as many tables, as many combinations of properties?

Comment: it depends a lot on how you are planning to use them

Comment: you said you wanted to run queries on those who had a common set of properties, right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. The problem in inheritance is the situation, in which I have several projects inheriting one, in which more than two (but not every) are collecting information X - then I need to iterate across several tables. But if "that's the intrinsic problem of a dynamic data model", as said a_horse_with_no_name, I will have to limit flexibility and use this solution.

Comment: I see. Basically, you need multiple inheritance.

Comment: Well ... One table for one option, with 2 columns: ID and value, and then one table for one project template, which basically is an empty table but inherits from particular option-tables ... If this work exactly how I expect, this is really great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Put all properties that you can already define and which are "constant" (and common to all members) into real columns of your table. For anything that is dynamic you can use the hstore datatype.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html

It's much better (more flexible and faster) than Oracle's ANYDATA

Comment: The hstore can be really useful thing, but what is the problem with it: "Keys and values are simply text strings". If I would assume, that every values are TEXT type, I could create table "Properties", in which I would have pairs like "PropertyID" and "PropertyName", and then table "Projects-Properties", in which I would have columns: "ProjectID", "PropertyID" and "value" as text. But what's the problem: since the values are different data types, converting strings to decimal values within the range queries (e.g. where something between 1.54 and 2.36) would be as slow, as burdensome.

Comment: @Krzysiek: that's the intrinsic problem of a dynamic data model.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand with the information provided, the data is not Relational. I feel you should look at NoSql options here.